# Why does the A-star algorithm need g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, a-star

Dijkstra's algorithm is `f(n) = g(n)`
and A* is `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)`.

g(n) is the cost of the path from the start node to n.
h(n) is a heuristic function that estimates the cost of the cheapest path from n to the goal.

Is g(n) needed? Can't it find the shortest path without g(n)?

Why does A* need g(n)?

Comment: The purpose is to get faster to the objective, so you influence it in a way that you expect to be in the right direction. But of course, the solution must be the same.

Comment: i don't know why it is faster, can you show some example?

Comment: Sorry, no. Just think that the algorithm progresses along a border and knows the best costs inside that border. If the border grows in all directions, it takes longer to fill it.

Answer (score 2):

### We need `g(n)`

Consider the case when `h(n)` is `0` for all nodes on some given path to the goal (which is a perfectly valid, i.e. admissible, heuristic) and non-zero for all other nodes.

If we ignore the cost so far (`g(n)`), clearly we will pick the nodes on this path no matter what the *actual* cost is, so the path we end up with can have a much greater cost than some other path.

```
               start
       g(n)=0    O --
               5 |   \ 1
h(n)=0,g(n)=5    O    O h(n)=1,g(n)=1
               5 |   / 1
h(n)=0,g(n)=10   O --
               goal
```

In the above example, we will pick the node on the left, and then the goal, since `h(n) = 0` for both (which is greater than `h(n) = 1` for the node on the right). This will give us a path with cost `10`, where the cheapest path involves picking the node on the right, for a cost of `2`.

This is perhaps an extreme example, but the same idea applies in many other cases. For example, you could also add 10 to all values in my example and have it be part of a larger graph and it would still end up incorrectly picking the left side above the right.

The more general conclusion here is that you can have a choice between 2 nodes `n1` and `n2` where `h(n1) < h(n2)`, thus we'll pick `n1`, but `n2` is on the cheapest path, not `n1`.

We can also pick the wrong node if we include `g(n)`. But, in that case, for some node `n` on the path including `n1`, `f(n)` will be greater than the cheapest path (in the worst case `n` will be the goal and `f(n)` will be the true cost to reach it through `n1`, which is clearly more expensive than the actual cheapest path), and thus also greater than `f(n2)` (since a heuristic needs to underestimate the cost), so we'll explore `n2` before reaching the goal.

### If `h(n)` were the true cost (and not an *estimate*)

Then we indeed wouldn't need `g(n)`.

But only considering `h(n)` will make it a greedy algorithm in this case (assuming nonnegative edge weights), since `h(n)` will decrease for each node we pick (since we're moving close to the goal), so at the starting node we'd pick a node on the optimal path (since it will have the lowest `h(n)`), and from there we'll just keep picking nodes on the optimal path.

Comment: You only consider the extremes "h is useless" and "h is perfect", but the same holds true if e.g. h is the same value for just two nodes in the queue, but the g for those nodes is different.

Comment: @tobias_k Edited.