# Coefficients in cost function in A-star

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

I'd like to expand on this question :

[Why does the A-star algorithm need g(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420788/why-does-the-a-star-algorithm-need-gn)

Dijkstra's algorithm uses cost function *f(n) = g(n)*
whereas A* uses cost function *f(n) = g(n) + h(n)*, with *g(n)* being the cost of the path from the start node to node *n*, and *h(n)* is a heuristic function that estimates the cost of the cheapest path from node *n* to the goal.

It is clear from this question that A* needs its *g(n)* function in the cost function.
My question however is the following. Can one use the cost function :

*f(n) = αg(n) + (1-α)h(n)*

for some alpha *0<α<1* ?

I ask because in some cases I observed it can be much faster to prioritize (through a coefficient) estimated cost over already traversed cost. I am not sure however if this still results in an optimal trajectory?

EDIT : multiplying the heuristic ℎ() by some alpha 0<<1 is allowed, since this operation still underestimates if ℎ() already did (which is necessary to obtain the resulting optimal path). I am more concerned about the multiplying of ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global scale factor of *f*, assuming it is a positive scale, does not matter, because *f* is only used in a relative sense. Numbers scaled by some positive scale stay in the same order.

Therefore, *f(n) = αg(n) + (1-α)h(n)* may be rewritten as *f'(n) = g(n) + ((1-α)/α)h(n)*, which is not equal but equivalent. So while you are interested in scaling *g*, effectively that is equivalent to scaling *h* anyway, after factoring out the global scale.

The effect is scaling the heuristic by some amount, which is OK only as long as (1-α)/α ≤ 1 (so: α ≥ 0.5), and otherwise leads to the same trouble as usual with an inadmissible heuristic.